Chrome not recognizing custom policies set for an extension
I am trying to add a custom policy that I can read from my chrome extension. But for some reason chrome isn't even recognizing the policy as being set. When I go to chrome://policy/ nothing is being displayed.
I am following this article:
https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions/


Did you click Reload policies in chrome://policy?

I found out I was missing the schema.json file
schema.json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "tenant": {
            "title": "Tenant",
            "description": "Tenant Name",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}

manifest.json
storage: {
    managed_schema: "schema.json"
  },

